# python, generated a list by concatenating list dynamic variable

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is I have 2 list varialbe that are for example:

```
UPE_ENV=['AMPOMSU01','AMPOAGU01','ampwt12u01','AMPDSU01'] 
DEV_ENV=['AMPOMSD01','AMPOAGD01','ampwt12d01','AMPDST01']
```

I pass env variable.

mypathon.py -e DEV  // -e for env

I want to dynamically generate the value of DEV_ENV[3].

```
if env == 'DEV: 
    startOVD('start',env+'_ENV'[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to access the relevant list based on the value of `env` that is being passed? If they are static lists like you show the easiest way would be to put them in a dictionary:

```
ENV_DICT = {
    "UPE_ENV": ['AMPOMSU01','AMPOAGU01','ampwt12u01','AMPDSU01'],
    "DEV_ENV": ['AMPOMSD01','AMPOAGD01','ampwt12d01','AMPDST01']
}
```

You could then fetch it from this dict:

```
env_list = ENV_DICT[env + '_ENV']
startOVD('start',env_list[3])
```

If you're always calling `startOVD` in the same way regardless of `env`'s value you don't need the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much @RiceKab